# Is "glass harmonicon" the same instrument as devised by Benjamin Franklin?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Is "glass harmonicon" the same instrument as devised by Benjamin Franklin?

> Moreover, actual contact is not always necessary. I have had these
> sounds proceeding from the floor, walls, etc., when the medium's hands
> and feet were held—when she was standing on a chair— when she was
> suspended in a swing from the ceiling—when she was enclosed in a wire
> cage—and when she had fallen fainting on a sofa. I have heard them on
> a **glass harmonicon**—I have felt them on my own shoulder and under
> my own hands.

*[The History of Spiritualism](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks03/0301051h.html#chap11)*   By A.C Doyle
<sub>XI.THE RESEARCHES OF SIR WILLIAM CROOKES (1870-1874)</sub>

Comment: _Does X is Y?_ is not correct English - you should ask _Is X Y?" or _does X mean Y?_

Answer (score 1):

"Harmonica" and "harmonicon" are interchangeable, though the latter is considered archaic by now. According to [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=harmonicon%2C%20harmonica&year_start=1500&year_end=2019&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Charmonicon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Charmonica%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Charmonicon%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Charmonica%3B%2Cc0), "harmonica" and "harmonicon" were used with roughly the same frequency in the 1870s, around the time Arthur Conan Doyle was a young man, so it is likely that he could have used either word at the time of writing *The History of Spiritualism* (1926) without any of his contemporary readership being vexed.

In the future, you should provide sources for the quotes you need help with, as context is always helpful for anyone trying to answer your questions.

Comment: https://www.alasdairmalloy.com/glass-harmonica/ is it the same instrument?

Comment: If your question is whether "glass harmonica" and "glass harmonicon" are the same instrument, then yes. If you are asking whether it is Benjamin Franklin's revision of the instrument, I couldn't possibly say.

Comment: ok. i was confused about the musical instrument but your answer settled my question. in the following sentence the author says: "I have heard them on a sheet of
paper, held between the fingers by a piece of thread passed through one
corner. " what does "passed through one corner" mean? i mean; did the thread passed through the paper?

Comment: If taken literally, then yes, almost certainly. I'm not at all familiar with early 20th century spiritualism, so I can't help you with any further context.

Comment: so he put the paper between his fingers and passed a thread through the paper to hold it?